How to exclude a particular column in a text file using UNIX "cut" command
Basically, I'm looking for the compliment of the current UNIX command "cut".
If I have a text file as below
"1" , "cat" , "animal"
"2" , "parrot , "bird"
"3" , "mosquito" , "insect"

In the above text file, looking to use cut to exclude column-2 and print as below
"1" ,  "animal"
"2" ,  "bird"
"3" ,  "insect"

Typical cut command -> cut -f2 -d"," <file_name> => prints field 2, which is cat parrot mosquito, which I dont want. I want the output look like the above
I tried using "--compliment" with cut command - probably it is not supported in bash.

"2" , "parrot , "bird" is missing a quote. Is that a typo in the question or possible with real data?

Whether --compliment (really, it would be --complement) is supported by any version of cut is independent of what shell you use to run cut.

POSIX cut does not provide anyway to specify a complement, and asking for a version of cut that does would be off-topic as a software recommendation.

When all fileds have no internal quotes and are surrounded by quotes, you might try cut -d'"' -f1,2,3,5-, but when you need to count fields like this, you will be using the wrong tool for the job.

Maybe something like this: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" , "} {print $1,$3}' file

First make sure what special cases should be supported in your case, something like sed 's/ , '[^"]*'//' might fail as well.

what's the question? is there a 'complement' capability? how to remove the 2nd column? if the latter: cut -d"," -f1,3

@Mike: Your question is not entirely consistent. Your cut -f2 -d","  would not yield mosquito, but "mosquito".
